# When is it appropriate to use a Scala Extractor?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching

Most of the Scala extractor examples are for relatively simple cases, for example:

- splitting an email address into username and domain so they can be matched separately
- splitting a name into first name and surname

Is it acceptable to use them for more advanced 'deserialisation' tasks, for example:

- splitting a line of CSV into a case class
- as an extension above, deserialisation of JSON into a case-class

I can think of a few reasons this might be desirable.  The match syntax makes it clear that you're handling the case when the CSV or JSON doesn't deserialise properly to the case class.

Longer term as your code (and data) evolve, you can extend your case classes / extractor / matcher to cater for an evolving schema.

Comment: No-one's going to stop you. Personally I'd prefer to use parser combinators for that kind of task though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're really designed for doing pattern matching. So if you find yourself doing some operations on a match, and you do it a few times in different places, it may be worth writing an extractor for that.

Personally I think that converting JSON to a case class is way to heavyweight to be an extractor, but something like identifying the type of a JSON string in a known format may well fit the bill.

For example you accept messages encoded in JSON but they all begin:

```
{"type":"Customer Order" ...
```

Then an extractor which identifies the Customer Order from the JSON encoded string would be quite convenient and maybe save you from parsing the whole string. Here's an example of how it would look.

```
object JSONMessage {
  def unapply(s: String) : Option[String] = {
    val pattern = "\\{\"type\":([\"'])(.*?)\\1".r
    pattern.findFirstMatchIn(s).map (_ group 2)
  }
}

val sample = """{"type":"Customer Order", "items", [1,2,3]}"""

sample match {
  case JSONMessage(msg) =>
    println(s"msg type is $msg")
}

val sample2 = """{"type":"Remove Items", "itemsToRemove", [1,2,3]}"""

sample2 match {
  case JSONMessage("Remove Items") =>
    println("Remove items message")
  case _ =>
    println("not the message we wanted")
}

val sample3 = """{"badlyFormed":"I'm not a message"}"""

sample3 match {
  case JSONMessage("Remove Items") =>
    println("Remove items message")
  case _ =>
    println("not the message we wanted")
}
```

This is a little brittle because if your incoming messages are not formatted exactly right it will fail to parse them, but I think it's a reasonable example of using extractors to simplify matching.

Comment: Thank you, and appreciate the example.  It's hard sometimes to get a grasp of best practise use of Scala in production applications.